# WPF Side Menu and Dynamically Display Items

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am creating a WPF Window with a side menu.  When a user clicks one of the side menu items I want to display certain text boxes, drop down menus, buttons. These will be different depending on which menu is clicked.

Do I need to define all possible items in the xaml or can these items be built and events handled dynamically in C#?

Comment: please post what you have in code so far.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out how to code and display different grids.  Now I can't figure out how to get the values from my controls in the grid.  My code:

private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //***  Database Menu Click  ***

```
        grdExcel.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        grdDatabase.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        //grdDataScrubber.Children.Remove(grdExcel);

        // ... Cast sender object.
        MenuItem item = sender as MenuItem;
        // ... Change Title of this window.
        Title = "Process " + item.Header + " Files";


        //InitializeGrid(grdDatabase, item);
        //AddDatabaseControls();
        //grdDataScrubber.Children.Add(grdDatabase);
    }

    private void MenuItem_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //***  Excel Menu Click  ***
        Label lblExcelInfo = new Label();

        grdDatabase.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        grdExcel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        //grdDataScrubber.Children.Remove(grdDatabase);

        // ... Cast sender object.
        MenuItem item = sender as MenuItem;
        // ... Change Title of this window.
        Title = "Process " + item.Header + " Files";

        //InitializeGrid(grdExcel);
        //lblExcelInfo.Content = "In Excel";
        //grdExcel.Children.Add(lblExcelInfo);
        //grdDataScrubber.Children.Add(grdExcel);
    }


    private void InitializeGrid(Grid gridArea)
    {
        gridArea.Height = 330;
        gridArea.Width = 650;
        gridArea.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        gridArea.Margin = new Thickness
        {
            Bottom = 0,
            Left = 70,
            Top = 0,
            Right = 0
        };
        gridArea.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        //gridArea.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(04, 149, 168));

        grdDataScrubber.Children.Add(gridArea);
    }


    private void AddDatabaseControls()
    {
        int intNumCols = 7;
        int intNumRows = 15;
        int intControlHeight = 20;
        ColumnDefinition[] cols = new ColumnDefinition[intNumCols];
        RowDefinition[] rows = new RowDefinition[intNumRows];
        Label lblGridTitle = new Label();
        Label lblDBInstance = new Label();
        ComboBox cbxDBInstances = new ComboBox();
        Button btnLoadDBInfo = new Button();
        Label lblDBName = new Label();
        ComboBox cbxDBName = new ComboBox();
        Label lblTableName = new Label();
        ComboBox cbxTableName = new ComboBox();
        Label lblOutputName = new Label();
        TextBox txtOutputFolder = new TextBox();
        Button btnBrowseFolder = new Button();
        Button btnSubmit = new Button();


        InitializeDatabaseColumns(intNumCols, cols);
        InitializeDatabaseRows(intNumRows, rows);

        lblGridTitle.Content = "Enter Database Info";
        lblGridTitle.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");
        lblGridTitle.FontSize = 13;
        lblGridTitle.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
        Grid.SetRow(lblGridTitle, 1);
        Grid.SetColumn(lblGridTitle, 1);
        grdDatabase.Children.Add(lblGridTitle);

        lblDBInstance.Content = "Enter Database Instance:";
        lblDBInstance.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");
        lblDBInstance.FontSize = 11;
        lblDBInstance.Height = intControlHeight;
        Grid.SetRow(lblDBInstance, 3);
        Grid.SetColumn(lblDBInstance, 1);
        grdDatabase.Children.Add(lblDBInstance);

        cbxDBInstances.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");
        cbxDBInstances.FontSize = 11;
        cbxDBInstances.Height = intControlHeight;
        Grid.SetRow(cbxDBInstances, 3);
        Grid.SetColumn(cbxDBInstances, 3);
        grdDatabase.Children.Add(cbxDBInstances);

        btnLoadDBInfo.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");
        btnLoadDBInfo.FontSize = 11;
        btnLoadDBInfo.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
        btnLoadDBInfo.Content = "Load DB Info";
        btnLoadDBInfo.Width = 75;
        btnLoadDBInfo.IsEnabled = false;
        btnLoadDBInfo.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(btnLoadDBInfo_Click);
    //    btnLoadDBInfo.Click = new System.EventHandler(btnLoadDBInfo_Click);
        Grid.SetRow(btnLoadDBInfo, 3);
        Grid.SetColumn(btnLoadDBInfo, 5);

        lblDBName.Content = "Choose Database:";
        lblDBName.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");
        lblDBName.FontSize = 11;
        lblDBName.Height = intControlHeight;
        Grid.SetRow(lblDBName, 5);
        Grid.SetColumn(lblDBName, 1);
        grdDatabase.Children.Add(lblDBName);

        cbxDBName.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");
        cbxDBName.FontSize = 11;
        cbxDBName.Height = intControlHeight;
        Grid.SetRow(cbxDBName, 5);
        Grid.SetColumn(cbxDBName, 3);
        grdDatabase.Children.Add(cbxDBName);

        lblTableName.Content = "Choose Database:";
        lblTableName.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");
        lblTableName.FontSize = 11;
        lblTableName.Height = intControlHeight;
        Grid.SetRow(lblTableName, 7);
        Grid.SetColumn(lblTableName, 1);
        grdDatabase.Children.Add(lblTableName);

        cbxTableName.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");
        cbxTableName.FontSize = 11;
        cbxTableName.Height = intControlHeight;
        Grid.SetRow(cbxTableName, 7);
        Grid.SetColumn(cbxTableName, 3);
        grdDatabase.Children.Add(cbxTableName);

        lblOutputName.Content = "Choose Output Folder:";
        lblOutputName.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");
        lblOutputName.FontSize = 11;
        lblOutputName.Height = intControlHeight;
        Grid.SetRow(lblOutputName, 9);
        Grid.SetColumn(lblOutputName, 1);
        grdDatabase.Children.Add(lblOutputName);

        txtOutputFolder.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");
        txtOutputFolder.FontSize = 11;
        txtOutputFolder.Height = intControlHeight;
        Grid.SetRow(txtOutputFolder, 9);
        Grid.SetColumn(txtOutputFolder, 3);
        grdDatabase.Children.Add(txtOutputFolder);

        btnBrowseFolder.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");
        btnBrowseFolder.FontSize = 11;
        btnBrowseFolder.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
        btnBrowseFolder.Content = "Browse...";
        btnBrowseFolder.Width = 60;
        btnBrowseFolder.IsEnabled = false;
        Grid.SetRow(btnBrowseFolder, 9);
        Grid.SetColumn(btnBrowseFolder, 5);
        grdDatabase.Children.Add(btnBrowseFolder);

        btnSubmit.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");
        btnSubmit.FontSize = 11;
        btnSubmit.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
        btnSubmit.Content = "Submit";
        btnSubmit.Width = 50;
        btnSubmit.IsEnabled = false;
        Grid.SetRow(btnSubmit, 11);
        Grid.SetColumn(btnSubmit, 3);
        grdDatabase.Children.Add(btnSubmit);

        grdDatabase.Children.Add(btnLoadDBInfo);
    }


    public void InitializeDatabaseColumns(int intNumCols, ColumnDefinition[] cols)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < intNumCols; i++)
        {
            cols[i] = new ColumnDefinition();
            grdDatabase.ColumnDefinitions.Add(cols[i]);
        }

        cols[0].Width = new GridLength(15);
        cols[1].Width = new GridLength(150);
        cols[2].Width = new GridLength(10);
        cols[3].Width = new GridLength(200);
        cols[4].Width = new GridLength(10);
        cols[5].Width = new GridLength(200);
        cols[6].Width = new GridLength(30);
    }


    public void InitializeDatabaseRows(int intNumRows, RowDefinition[] rows)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < intNumRows; x++)
        {
            rows[x] = new RowDefinition();
            grdDatabase.RowDefinitions.Add(rows[x]);
            rows[x].Height = new GridLength(26);

            if (x % 2 == 0)
            {
                // Setting column width.
                rows[x].Height = new GridLength(15);
            }

        }
        rows[0].Height = new GridLength(5);
        rows[1].Height = new GridLength(30);
        rows[10].Height = new GridLength(40);
    }
```

Comment: I need to get what is entered in cbxDBInstances.